# Requirement of RDS in citrix Xenapp essentials

Tags: azure, citrix, xenapp

I want to know what is the requirment of RDS in citrix xenapp essentials? I am new in these things and what to know as much as possible I have read about the documEntation of citrix xenapp essentials but was unable to figure out whats the is a use of RDS server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the XenApp Essentials Service guide: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-cloud/xenapp-and-xendesktop-service/xenapp-essentials.html

The XenApp Essentials Service offering accesses Windows Server remote session capabilities that would typically require a Remote Desktop Services client access license (RDS CAL). The Virtual Delivery Agent (VDA) must be able to contact a Remote Desktop license server to request RDS CALs. You are required to install and activate the license server. For more information, see Activate the Remote Desktop Services License Server. 
For POC environments, you can use the grace period provided by Microsoft.

You can bring your own license server from on-premises or stand up a new one.